# Fix Pytesseract OCR output being rotated

Tags: python, opencv, decimal, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to OCR the image of the waypoints like this, and I want the output to be exactly the same as the following image:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image
import cv2

# Set Tesseract executable path
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread("wp1.png")
text = tess.image_to_string(img)
```

I got the output vertically, but I want it to show horizontally.
I want to have output format like lats long Alt on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not optimal, but if you use it like the doc describe it you get three columns:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('wp1.png')

custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
print(text)
```

You get:

```
-35.363219 149.164976 577.419983
-35.357360 149.163171 10.000000
-35.364753 149.155083 10.000000
-35.369599 149.166029 10.000000
-35.364753 149.171295 10.000000
...
```

Comment: It works thank you very much I have a futhermore question  custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)  what does it do in this line of code

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it was helpful. You can find [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) more info about image_to_string, image_to_data, etc.